# Why doesn't the clause "....and reputation its shadow" need a verb?

Tags: ellipsis, relative-clauses, gapping

The clause "reputation its shadow" in "Character is like a tree and reputation its shadow" has no verb, but is still correct. Please kindly tell me the grammar point used here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a shortened expression. Instead of using "is" two times, one shortly after the other, the second "is" is dropped and the meaning does not become unclear.
Read the sentence as:

Character is like a tree and reputation (is) its shadow.

Comment: The request is for a grammar point in use, vs. what it means.  ["shortening"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12910/) seems to have another meaning.

Comment: @HostileFork   The poster asks why  there  is no verb between reputation and shadow. But thanks fot the hint at my wrong use of "shortening". What non-native speaker can guess that shortening is a kitchen expression. So I have to use the technical term ellipsis.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving out a word (ellipsis) is sometimes used to avoid repetition. When we have two sentences with the same pattern and the same verb we don't need to repeat the verb.

> ...reputation (is) it's shadow