# Is there a 'should be' missing in this sentence?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, modality

[image: Source]

Shouldn't it be 'and the sale (should) be delayed'?

'Should' is in the bracket because it is self-understood maybe.

Comment: I agree with your idea.. 'should be' seems to be left out for repeatation.

Comment: Similar sentences in some old questions: *[Approval was given, and Ju's art displayed](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/67405/3281)*; *[Character is like a tree and reputation its shadow](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/82466/3281)*.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct as written. The proposed action (delaying the sale) will occur when the specified conditions (including investigation by the FBI) are met. If the FBI does not investigate, the other actions are meaningless.

If you use "the sale (should be) delayed" you are making the delay optional after the FBI starts investigating. It *should* be delayed, but maybe not in case of xxx. Given the reason for the delay, I doubt that is the intent here.

Comment: I don't agree with this analysis. I don't find any difference in meaning whether the "should be" is there or not: it can be deleted bacause repeated items in coordinate structures (here, the verb in two clauses joined by 'and') can often be deleted.

Comment: The "delay" is contingent on the "investigation". Whether the "delay" happens depends on their process. It could be either way. So I would not assume "should" belongs in "the sale (should be) delayed".