# Strange omission of "to be": "The ground was hard and the rime thick and crisp on the grass."

Tags: grammar, meaning, verbs, ellipsis

I encountered this sentence in Cambridge Dictionary:

> The ground was hard and ***the rime thick and crisp*** on the grass.

I can't figure it out why there's no any verb after "the rime". It just doesn't make sense to me.

"The ground **was** hard" - that's ok. "The rime **(*was??*)** thick and crisp on the grass" - why is there such an omission of the verb?

Considering the fact that the sentence is actually provided as an example for the word "rime" on the Cambridge website, so i'm sure it's correct, but i've literally no idea what that thing means.

English is not my native, so for me it's still pretty difficult to comprehend these things.

Comment: Another reason for this phrasing could be to fit a poetic rhythm (here, typical of a ballad). Although that kind of elision with parallel clauses is normal, this sentence sounds more like verse than natural speech.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't the clause "....and reputation its shadow" need a verb?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/82466/why-doesnt-the-clause-and-reputation-its-shadow-need-a-verb)

Comment: Check out the Prayer of St. Francis of Assissi https://www.cathedralstm.org/about-our-catholic-faith/expressing-our-faith/treasury-catholic-prayers/prayer-st-francis-assisi-prayer-peace/

Comment: "The house was red and the car blue": Same omission. The repetition would be redundant. Your example is just a bit more elaborate.

Answer (score 63):

It's quite normal in English, when two short parallel clauses need the same verb, for that verb not to be repeated:

> I wore a blue dress and my sister a red one.
>
> Peter was born in Scotland and Paul in England.

instead of

> I wore a blue dress and my sister *wore* a red one.
>
> Peter was born in Scotland and Paul *was born* in England.

. It would not be wrong to repeat the verb, but English speakers find that the sentence sounds better without it.

Comment: I would add that English teachers in non English-speaking countries tend to teach that in English you *must* put a verb there. This is common in Italy (especially in basic or mid-level courses, or in schools) and often this "rule" is explained by contrasting it with Italian language, where such omissions are common.

Comment: FWIW, this feels British to me. As a Canadian, I'd repeat both "be" and "wore" in almost all circumstances.

Comment: As an American (specifically: California), I can corroborate that this is not inherently a Britishism. While the first example sentence sounds better with "wore" repeated, it sounds perfectly grammatical to me either way. The second example sentence would also sound perfectly grammatical either way, but feels more native-English-speaker to me the way it's phrased above.

Comment: This is known in linguistics as [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)), specifically as [gapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gapping). Ellipsis is also the name of the punctuation mark "[…](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis)", which I imagine to be very confusing for English students.

Comment: I think this style of dropping the verb after the first parallel clause is more likely to be found in highbrow literature and carefully prepared speeches. I really don't hear this omission in conversational speech. I think a good reason is that it exercises short term memory harder, increasing the chance for confusion.

Comment: To me it sounds kind of flowery or poetic with the verb omitted.

Comment: "Quite normal" is, as all things are, relative. Spoken English shows this phenomenon, but it is rare. Spoken German, for instance, makes much more use of it, and Japanese can use gaps that span three or four levels of syntactic relation, and that Westerners initially find almost undecipherable.

Comment: Well, the sentence quoted by the OP (a dictionary example) sounds like literature rather than conversational English.

Comment: @KilianFoth It is also quite common in Dutch, both spoken and written.

Answer (score -2):

I believe that this is a style indicative of dialog or verse that reduces words for brevity and familiarity.  Which that last sentence certainly did not..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).